How to display 3 horizontal nested tabs on mobile device
There is a tab with 5 options: Upload Documents, Personal Profile, Financial Profile, Bank Account, and Nominee. When Upload Documents is selected, 2 more tabs appear below it. The 2nd tab has 4 options: Applicant 1, Applicant 2, Applicant 3, and Common. By default, Applicant 1 is selected, and it contains a nested tab with 3 options: PAN, Aadhaar, and Photograph. In the mobile UI, displaying these 3 tabs stacked one below the other looks unappealing. these are few variations which i tried. What are some alternative design approaches for displaying these 3 tabs in the mobile UI?

What do you mean with "unappealing"? I see three functional nested tabs. It's about design?

Yes, unappealing from ui point of view. Due to that I came up with this ui (in the above image) 2 tabs and group button instead of 3 horizontal tabs.

Are we talking responsive only or is adaptive layout an option? If you can go Adaptive you could reconsider 1 or 2 lines of tabs by pushing them into a menu, or perhaps open Applicant 1 in a new page on mobile where you can hide the top lvl.

Only for mobile ui. I thought so but as per the requirement all the 3 tabs should be visible as they are linked to each other. On click of documents user gets to see the applicant and on click of any applicant user can upload their data. So they didn't want to hide any of the tab.

If its only about showing the path, a breadcrumb might also be an option
Upload documents > Applicant 1 > PAN.
In the end a tab is a tab, you can design them to look better but they'll always be a bit clunky, especially when you have 3 rows stacked. Therefore, if the goal is clarity and a more appealing/clean design, breadcrumbs/menu's/new pages are options to consider and try

I think there is some structural changes that you could make:

Group them by applicants (accounts).
Provide one full page for the applicants form.
Have a page to list all applicants and their form fill up progress. And then navigate one layer deeper from this page to access the form.

It could look like this:

Through this you could reduce the clutter, make it more mobile optimised and grouped well aligned to the user flow (I did make some assumptions on the user flow here based on general form knowledge.)

I had the same problem for a multi-stepper component. In my case it was for a web app, and the solution is presented in this question.
Kish is solving your problem in a really good way, since you have to re-structure your IA to use his suggestion.
In my case, the user was following a process to make changes to one project, for each step they needed to submit different documentation that's why I was not able to modify the IA. Even though my approach was responsive I think it is not scalable for a mobile platform, due space limitations.
Hope I can help you, happy designs... 

Thank you so much for your help and suggestions. The client wanted to maintain the hierarchy structure without using three horizontal tabs, so I tried three different variations. The first and second variations received the most votes, but the third variation was ultimately chosen. Let me know your thoughts on these. 

For 1 and 2: Do you still find it "unappealing"?    For 3: I think the dropdown is a combination of two dropdowns (applicant selection & information). I don't think its the right component to use here.

The first variation was actually great in terms of UI and UX, as it clearly displayed all the required documents for users at a glance, and allowed for easy navigation without needing to remember anything. In the second variation, I combined two tabs since PAN, Aadhaar, and photo were common for all three applicants. However, this led to horizontal scrolling for each applicant's PAN, Aadhaar, and photo combination, which I felt resulted in excessive horizontal scrolling. 3rd was selected as it was easy for implementation and for easy decision making for users.
